# Sending a file via email using VBScript

Tags: vbscript, outlook

I am trying to send a file via email using VBScript and i am facing some issues with it:

```
Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set objMail = objOutlook.CreateItem(0)
objMail.To = "abc@abc.com.sg"
objMail.Subject = "2pm BB BFix File"
objMail.Body = "2pm BB BFix File attached"
objMail.Attachments.Add("\\Market Risk\Market Risk - Trading\BFix\Request Files\BFIX_Afternoon_Output.req")
objMail.Send  
Set objMail = Nothing
Set objOutlook = Nothing
```

It is giving me this error:

> \\Market Risk. Cannot find the file.

Not sure why this error is popping out when I am not opening the file.

Comment: Can you get to `\\Market Risk\Market Risk - Trading\BFix\Request Files\BFIX_Afternoon_Output.req` if you manually locate it through Windows Explorer? I'm not sure if `Attachments.Add()` accepts a UNC as a valid path, you might have to map it to a drive letter first so something like `E:\BFix\Request Files\BFIX_Afternoon_Output.req` after `\\Market Risk\Market Risk - Trading` is mapped to `E:`.

Comment: Checked and it should take UNC paths, so the problem could be permissions or it doesn't like the spaces in the file path, could you try `objMail.Attachments.Add("""\\Market Risk\Market Risk - Trading\BFix\Request Files\BFIX_Afternoon_Output.req""")` this will produce `"\\Market Risk\Market Risk - Trading\BFix\Request Files\BFIX_Afternoon_Output.req"` encapsulating the path.

Comment: I can access \\Market Risk\Market Risk - Trading\BFix\Request Files\BFIX_Afternoon_Output.req in the Windows Explorer

Comment: objMail.Attachments.Add("""\\Market Risk\Market Risk - Trading\BFix\Request Files\BFIX_Afternoon_Output.req""") => tried this as well

Comment: Is the error any different with the encapsulated path approach?

Comment: The error is the same.

Comment: It could possibly be permissions *(but the error doesn't suggest that)*, try running the script in an elevated command prompt.

Comment: it is definitely not permissions. what do u mean by elevated command prompt?

Comment: UAC (User Account Control) was introduced some time ago now in Windows Operating Systems. Even logged in as an Administrator certain application will run in a *"limited"* mode and not truly as "Administrator". This is especially true with scripts, try this find `Command Prompt` right click `Run as administrator` you should notice when the window appears it's prefixed with `Administrator: Command Prompt`. Navigate to where your script is located and type `cscript //nologo yourscript.vbs` and it will run with elevated permissions.

Comment: This might help - [How to run vbs as administrator from vbs?](//stackoverflow.com/q/17466681) and [Best way to know if a user has administrative privileges from a VBScript](//stackoverflow.com/q/301860)

Comment: Hostnames must not contain spaces, so `\\Market Risk\...` is not a valid UNC path, which would have the form `\\server\share\sub\folder`.

Comment: how to fix this error?

Comment: Do not use a server with a space in its name.

Comment: That’s a great spot @AnsgarWiechers didn’t even think about that. Did say [could they access it from Windows Explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51436480/sending-a-file-via-email-using-vbscript#comment89843793_51436480) and [they said yes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51436480/sending-a-file-via-email-using-vbscript#comment89844535_51436480) so just assumed it was a valid path.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers Just had a look myself and [Microsoft doesn’t suggest that server names can’t contain spaces](https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/help/909264/naming-conventions-in-active-directory-for-computers-domains-sites-and) *(see NetBIOS computer names)*, even though it would make sense to me not to.

Comment: @Lankymart Even if they don't explicitly say it's not allowed: try actually setting a hostname that has a space in it.

Comment: @AnsgarWiechers wasn’t disagreeing just stating what I’d found. It’s ages since I’ve done any network stuff in VBScript i’m writing this on my iPhone, so can’t try right now.

Comment: Try using the servers IP address instead of the name.